# Sudoers Permissions

Tags: permissions, sudoers

opensuse 12.1

I'm creating a file in **/etc/sudoers.d/** called access. The permissions are set at 0440
This works fine.

Currently the file has just this in it:

```
www ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Which allows my web scripts to run anything as root without a password. ( I know it's not secure )

I'd like to allow www to run as root with out a password for 3 scripts only.

```
/application/local/dev/install -lan
/application/local/test/install -lan
/application/local/support/install -lan
```

Can that be done ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this and it worked :)

I created a plain text file and added the following

```
www ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /application/local/dev/install -lan
www ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /application/local/test/install -lan
www ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /application/local/support/install -lan
```

I then set the files permissions to 0440 and copied to to /etc/sudoers.d/

Following that my www user still has root access to these files with out a password, but not to anything else.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.